# how is the image represented in array format when we use writable raster to obtain byte array from bufferedimage?

Tags: java, image-processing

I used the code below to convert the image into array.But i am not able to understand how the pixels are represented in the array as the array is one dimensional  and the image is a grid of pixels. also i am not able to understand the meaning of values obtained in the array.

```
 WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage .getRaster();
 DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
 byte[] b=data.getData();
```

P.S- I am new to java

edit: what will be the size of the byte array

Comment: An image is represented as a 2 dimensional form, but it's still essentially just a (1D) sequence of pixels. If you want to know the size of the array, you can print out `b.length` to find out.

Answer (score 0):

A `TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` `BufferedImage` will be represented as a 1D array of byte.

So the pixel values will be into the range [-128, 127], and if you need to have the value within the range [0, 256], you will have to use `b[i] & 0xFF`.

Now for ALL the different `BufferedImage` types, the `DataBuffer`is always a 1D array, which contains the rows put one after the other. So instead of having a classical 2D array like

> p1 p2 p3
>
> p4 p5 p6
>
> p7 p8 p9

you will have

> p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9

So the size of the DataBuffer (byte array in your case) is `width x height`, so in your example `b.length` is equal to `bufferedImage.getWidth()* bufferedImage.getHeight()`

If your image is of type `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`, then it is encoded like that:

> b1 g1 r1 b2 g2 r2 b3 g3 r3 b4 g4 r4 b5 g5 r5 b6 g6 r6 b7 g7 r7 b8 g8 r8 b9 g9 r9

Then the size of the DataBuffer is  `3 x width x height`.

Comment: I compared the length of the array to the product of height and width and it does not match

Comment: It must if your image is TYPE_BYTE_GRAY. Check the `getType()`, you will certainly find that it's not TYPE_BYTE_GRAY, but TYPE_3BYTE_BGR or TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR

Comment: It's also possible that the raster represents a "view" of another raster (in the case of a `BufferedImage` returned from `.getSubimage(...)` for instance). If so, the length of array will still represent the size of the original, not the cropped version. This is regardless of type. So, use with care.